# Compilation error installing nodetime

Tags: node.js, compiler-errors, nodetime

I'm trying to install the nodetime module (for node), but when I do, I get the following compilation error:

> make: *** [Release/obj.target/nodetime_native/src/nodetime_native.o]
>   Error 1 make: Leaving directory
>   `/home/fernando/node_modules/nodetime-native/build' gyp ERR! build
>   error  gyp ERR! stack Error:`make` failed with exit code: 2 gyp ERR!
>   stack     at ChildProcess.onExit
>   (/home/fernando/apps/node-v0.12.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23) gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17) gyp ERR!
>   stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (child_process.js:1074:12) gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-53-generic gyp
>   ERR! command "node"
>   "/home/fernando/apps/node-v0.12.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
>   "rebuild" gyp ERR! cwd /home/fernando/node_modules/nodetime-native gyp
>   ERR! node -v v0.12.2 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3 gyp ERR! not ok  npm
>   ERR! Linux 3.13.0-53-generic npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node"
>   "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i" "nodetime-native" npm ERR! node v0.12.2 npm
>   ERR! npm  v2.7.4 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! nodetime-native@0.1.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild` npm ERR!
>   Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the nodetime-native@0.1.0
>   install script 'node-gyp rebuild'. npm ERR! This is most likely a
>   problem with the nodetime-native package, npm ERR! not with npm
>   itself. npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system: npm
>   ERR!     node-gyp rebuild npm ERR! You can get their info via: npm
>   ERR!     npm owner ls nodetime-native npm ERR! There is likely
>   additional logging output above.

Looking around, it would seem like I need to have Python installed, which I do (both 2.7 and 3.4) and make and gcc, which I do.
What else could be happening here?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to make sure the Python executable you reach via your PATH environment variable leads to the 2.x version.

I believe node-gyp isn't working well with the 3.x version of Python.